# How to find the groups of a given user in activiti?

Tags: java, alfresco, activiti, business-process-management

I use activiti enterprise and I have synced all groups and users from Keycloak to activiti.

I can see all the groups and users when I click on organizations tab in activiti.

I am trying to get the group of a given user programmatically.

```
public List<String> getGroups(String email){    

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    User user = userService.findUserByEmail(email);

    myList = user.getGroups().stream().map(gr -> gr.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    myList.stream().forEach(gr -> System.out.println("group name" + gr));

    return myList;

}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.activiti.domain.idm.User.groups, could not initialize proxy - no Session
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:569)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:188)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:548)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:126)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:266)
at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.estimateSize(Spliterators.java:1821)
at java.util.Spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(Spliterator.java:408)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:480)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at com.xyz.service.MyUserService.getGroups(MyUserService.java:120)
```

Is there a way which I can get the groups of a given user or iterate through all the groups to find if a user exist in any of the groups?

Answer (score 0):

When your managed entities were joined with a `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` or just without an explicit definition of a fetch type (if it's without definition then [it depends on a type of relationship](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/entity-mappings-introduction-jpa-fetchtypes/)) then fetching of a joined entity must be done within a transaction. So you have to annotate your method with a `@Transactional`

Answer (score 0):

It is not always advised to change the `fetchType` unless you are sure you always need to load this association.

Perhaps you should consider the use of [entity graphs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/EntityGraph.html) which would allow you to fetch your user object and it's groups when required.

E.g.

```
@NamedEntityGraphs({
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "User.groups",
    attributeNodes = {
            @NamedAttributeNode(value = "groups")
    })
})
```

Then you could add the entity graph to your repository method like below to fetch a user and their groups

```
@EntityGraph("User.groups")
List<User> findUserByEmail(String email);
```

EDIT:

Alternatively if all you code wishes to do is fetch the user's groups then you could craft a JPA query to just select those groups rather than the larger entity graph that is a user and it's groups.

E.g.

```
@Query("SELECT user.groups FROM User user WHERE user.email = :email")
List<Group> findGroupsUserEmail(@Param("email") String email);
```

Comment: actually the entity graph quite the contrary supposed to change the fetch type. Imagine you have a joined property that is lazy and it is ok for the business logic, but in some certain case you need to get joined property immediately without lazy loading, right at this case the entity graph will be useful.

Comment: I think we are meaning the same thing, it is best to leave the `groups` lazy in this association unless the business logic dictates that they should always be eagerly fetched.